# I am having problems trying to print this hash using perl

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to work through a problem where I created a hash using

```perl
push @{ $test{$onecell2}{$onecell3}{$onecell4} }, $onecell1;
```

The reason for using this is due to the fact that the first 3 are repeated with multiple values which is the oncell1.

I am not able to print the hash because at the fourth level I am getting this error: `Nòt a HASH reference`

It would be great if somebody could help. Thanks

```perl
my %test;  

push @{ $test{$onecell2}{$onecell3}{$onecell4} }, $onecell1;

foreach my $name (sort keys %test) {
    foreach my $subject (keys %{ $test{$name} }) {
     foreach my $storage (keys %{ $test{$name}{$subject} }) {
      foreach my $size (keys %{ $test{$name}{$subject}{$storage} }) {
        print "$name: $subject: $storage: $size \n";
     }  
    }
   }
}
```

And the error is: `Not a HASH reference`

This is the hash structure

```perl
$VAR1 = {
      'A1RE' => {
           'Recombinant Human' => {                                       
               "Lyophilized protein " => [
                   '10 ug',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                   '50 ug',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                   '500 ug',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                   '1 mg'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
               ]                                                               
           }
      };
```

I expect the output to be:

```
 AIRE: Recombinant Human: Lyophilized protein: 10 ug,50 ug, 500 ug, 1mg.
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your last level is an array ref, not a hash. You need to use array dereference `@{ ... }` on an array reference:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %test = (
    'A1RE' => {
        'Recombinant Human' => {
            "Lyophilized protein " => [
                '10 ug',
                '50 ug',
                '500 ug',
                '1 mg',
            ],
        },
    },
);

foreach my $name (sort keys %test) {
    my $subjects = $test{$name};
    foreach my $subject (keys %{ $subjects }) {
        my $storages = $subjects->{$subject};
        foreach my $storage (keys %{ $storages }) {
            my $sizes = $storages->{$storage};
            print "$name: $subject: $storage: ", join(", ", @{ $sizes }), "\n";
        }
    }
}

exit 0;
```

Output:

```
$ perl dummy.pl 
A1RE: Recombinant Human: Lyophilized protein : 10 ug, 50 ug, 500 ug, 1 mg
```

Comment: What do you mean by "print"? The problem in your code is that you tried to use hash de-reference `%{ ... }` on an array reference. My [mcve] shows how to loop over an array reference.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the example data set instead. Maybe now it becomes more clear?

Comment: That is great but then it duplicates the results for me. So in my example the variable $onecell1 has multiple values and then it prints out multiple times. THe whole idea of creating the hash was to remove the duplicates and have a single field for the values. Thanks for the advice. I will keep it in mind and thanks again for your code.

Comment: OK, I think I got it now. I've removed the last loop and replaced it with a `join()` for the array element.

Comment: Is your problem solved now, i.e. can we close this question?